# StoreKit.StoreKitError.unknown thrown by try await Product.products(for: productIdentifiers) using StorekitTest testcases

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, in-app-purchase, storekit

StoreKit.StoreKitError.unknown is being thrown by
try await Product.products(for: productIdentifiers)
when using StoreKitTest.framework to write testcases for In app purchase using the .configuration file.

imported following frameworks in file:

```
import XCTest
import StoreKitTest
```

Following code is not throwing any error

```
do{
    session = try SKTestSession(configurationFileNamed: "IAPSubscriptions")
    session?.resetToDefaultState()
    session?.disableDialogs = true
    session?.clearTransactions()
    XCTAssert(session != nil)
}catch{
    XCTFail("IAPSubscriptions.storekit configuration file could not be loaded")
}
```

Following code is throwing error:

```
do{
    let productIdentifier = "com.test.monthly_19"
    let products = try await store.requestWithProductIdentifiers(productIdentifiers: [productIdentifier])
    XCTAssert(products.count  1)
}catch{
    XCTFail() //StoreKit.StoreKitError.unknown
}
```

How shall I resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

If you see following logs in the console, you may be the same question with me.

> [Default] [StoreKit] Failed to get products through appstored in
> simulator, will try using appstoreagent on host mac: Error
> Domain=ASDErrorDomain Code=950 "Unhandled exception"
> UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unhandled exception,
> NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred}
>
> [Default][StoreKit] Received error that does not have a corresponding StoreKit
> Error: Error Domain=ASDErrorDomain Code=950 "Unhandled exception"
> UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unhandled exception,
> NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred}

For my case, only after I set the Host Application to my test target, can it works. Hope it helps to you.

[Host Application Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FuA3.png)